# How to find $X_i$ from this equation

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, estimation

Suppose

$X_i=\nu_i+\frac{m-i}{m}X_{i+1}+\frac{i}{m}X_{i-1},\quad 1\le i\le m$

where $X_0=X_{m+1}=0$. I need to find an expression for $X_i$ in terms of $v_i$, $i$, and $m$.
I know how to find it like inverse of a matrix, but I need a better presentation for it (like a closed form or a summation). Any help is greatly appreciated!
(I am not sure but I think it is like the equation of a non-causal auto-regressive model)

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $X$, the vector $X=(\begin{array}{cccc}X_0&X_1&\cdots&X_{m+1}\end{array})^T$ and by $v$, the vector $v=(\begin{array}{cccc}v_1&v_2&\cdots&v_{m}\end{array})^T$. Now your equation turns out to be 
$$-\frac{i}{m}X_{i-1}+X_i-\frac{m-i}{m}X_{i+1}=v_i,~~~1\leq i\leq m$$
Then $MX=v$ or $X=M^{-1}v$, where $M$ is a $m\times (m+2)$ matrix given by
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -\frac{m-1}{m} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
-\frac{2}{m} & 1 & -\frac{m-2}{m} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & -\frac{3}{m} & 1 & -\frac{m-3}{m}  & 0 & 0& \cdots\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{4}{m} & 1 & -\frac{m-4}{m}  & 0 & \cdots\\
\cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots\end{array} \right)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! but as I mentioned in the question, I already knew this matrix solution. I was looking for another form of solution, like a closed form or a summation.